# integrate mvc2 into existing webform webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, integration, webforms

HI,
i have large project which is created in asp.net webforms
I want to start using asp.net mvc withing the project.
How can i set it up? Have you some steps, helps guide pls?
thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

I have to convert existing website to web application. I have followed this guide
http://gurustop.net/blog/2008/08/03/converting-vs-2008-website-to-web-application/

Darin,
thank you for you info and it helped, as it gave me the right idea of approach.

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc) about how you could mix classic WebForms with ASP.NET MVC within the same application.

Comment: @Pavel, you also will likely need to update the project file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318640/adding-asp-net-mvc-to-webforms-application-how-do-i-get-mvc-menu-options-in-vs2